# Size of app with files in documents folder iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Will moving or creating files or images in application/Documents folder increase the size of your app in iOS? [Creating an app using phonegap]

Comment: It will use device memory, if you stored 2GB of data from your app, then 2GB memory will get reduced from your iDevice.

Comment: Document folder exits in your app sandbox.. Anything you put in it is the content of your app.

Comment: Thanks Mrunal and Rathore. @Rathore so, will it increase my app size or no?

Comment: Why are you concerning about app size? Here app size over device is different than the app downloading size from AppStore.

Comment: The thing is since, I am storing the files inside my app, the size of app is increasing, which we feel is  not efficient

Answer (score -1):

It is increasing my app size when I am trying to take pictures from my app and store it inside my applications' `Document` folder.